# convex cyclic quadrilateral ABCD

Tags: geometry

Points $E$ and $F$ are on side $BC$ of convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ (with $E$ closer than $F$ to $B$). It is known that $∠BAE = ∠CDF$ and $∠EAF = ∠FDE$. Prove that $∠FAC = ∠EDB$.

I have already deduced that ADFE is cyclic, and it suffices to prove ABCD is cyclic. However I am stuck at this point. I find it hard to use the angle condition $∠BAE = ∠CDF$.

Comment: Hint: I considered the sum of angles in triangle $CED$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I am blind.... thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADEF is cyclic, denote by $a$ its interior angle in $A$. Let $x$ be the common value of the two angles $\angle(BAE)$ and $\angle(FDC)$.

Then the angle in $A$ of $ABCD$ is $a+x$, and the exterior angle in $C$ of it is the exterior angle of the $\Delta CDF$ with angles $a$ (in $F$) and $x$ (in $D$), which is thus also $a+x$.

So $ABCD$ is cyclic.

[image: ABCD, a, and x]

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB \cap DE = G$ and $AF \cap DC = H$. Then the angle condition gives $\angle GAH = \angle GDH$, so $GADH$ cyclic. The second angle condition gives $\angle EAF = \angle EDF$ so $AEFD$ cyclic.

Now, angle chasing, we get $\angle AFD = \angle AED = \angle EAG + \angle AGE$, and $\angle AFE = \angle HFC = \angle DCB - \angle CHF = \angle DCB - \angle DGA$.

Adding these angles gives $\angle FDC + \angle DCF = \angle DFE = \angle AFD + \angle AFE = \angle BAE + \angle DCB$, so $\angle BAE = \angle FDC$.